# Is there any way to permanently display these settings after pressing the button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-development, game-loop

I try to display the list of settings after pressing the button, the problem is that I do it in the game loop and it is known that the text will appear and disappear over and over, is there any sensible way to get around it somehow?
Thanks in advance

```
def settings_show():
        draw_text('CONTROL:', font, WHITE, 115, 380),
        draw_text('JUMP', font, WHITE, 190, 410),
        screen.blit(Wkey, (140, 395)),
        draw_text('LEFT', font, WHITE, 55, 450),
        screen.blit(Dkey, (180, 435)),
        draw_text('RIGHT', font, WHITE, 230, 450),
        screen.blit(Akey, (100, 435)),
        draw_text('SHOOT', font, WHITE, 210, 490),
        screen.blit(SPkey, (125, 460)),
        draw_text('NADE', font, WHITE, 55, 546),
        screen.blit(Qkey, (5, 530)),
        draw_text('MUTE MUSIC', font, WHITE, 55, 586),
        screen.blit(Mkey, (5, 570)),
        draw_text('UNMUTE MUSIC', font, WHITE, 55, 626),
        screen.blit(Ukey, (5, 610)),
        draw_text('FULLSCREEN', font, WHITE, 55, 666),
        screen.blit(Fkey, (5, 650)),
        draw_text('TAKE SCREENSHOT', font, WHITE, 55, 706),
        screen.blit(F5key, (5, 690)),
        draw_text('EXIT', font, WHITE, 55, 746),
        screen.blit(ESCkey, (5, 730))
```

```
settings_button = button.Button(SCREEN_WIDTH // 1 - 1050, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 1 - 70, settings_img, 1)
```

```
        if start_button.draw(screen):
            start_game = True
            MENUSELECT.play()
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        if exit_button.draw(screen):
            MENUSELECT.play()
            run = False
            pygame.display.update()
        if settings_button.draw(screen):
            MENUSELECT.play()
            settings_show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `settings_show()` in the application loop. Instead of calling `settings_show()` when the button is pressed, set a state that indicates that the settings must be shown:

```py
game_state = "start_menu"

# application loop
while run:
    # [...]

    if game_state == "start_menu":
        if start_button.draw(screen):
            start_game = True
            MENUSELECT.play()
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        if exit_button.draw(screen):
            MENUSELECT.play()
            run = False
        if settings_button.draw(screen):
            MENUSELECT.play()
            game_state = "settings"


    elif game_state == "settings":
        settings_show()
```